# Table not adjusting to page

Tags: tables

I cannot make this table adjust to the page of my document, not even when I set font size to tiny.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

```
\begin{table}[htbp]  
\tiny 
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1in}{-1in} %
  \centering
  \caption{Pruebas de placebo}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\toprule
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)} \\
Variables & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Número de operaciones - ZINB} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Desembolsos - FEP} \\
    \midrule
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
Placebo 6 meses & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.05} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.11} \\
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.06)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.16)} \\
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
Placebo 9 meses & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.02} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.21} \\
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.05)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.16)} \\
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
Placebo 12 meses & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.09**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.31*} \\
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.04)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.16)} \\
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
Observaciones & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3,500} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3,500} \\
Efectos Fijos por Localidad & \multicolumn{1}{c}{SI} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{SI} \\
Dummies Temporales & \multicolumn{1}{c}{SI} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{SI} \\
Número de Localidades & \multicolumn{1}{c}{125} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{125} \\
\bottomrule
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textsuperscript{}\footnotesize{Nota: Período: septiembre 2011 a diciembre de 2013. Las variables placebo se definen como la variable tratamiento, rezagada 6, 9 y 12 meses.}} \\
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textsuperscript{}\footnotesize{Solo se reporta esta variable; cada regresión incluye todos los controles utilizados en las Tablas \ref{tab:noperaciones}, \ref{tab:desembolsos} y \ref{tab:credprom}. Errores clúster a nivel de localidad,}} \\
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textsuperscript{}\footnotesize{entre paréntesis. *** p<0.01, ** p<0.05, * p<0.1}}
\end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:placebo}%
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}%
```

Comment: Your text in the columns is most times too wide, it doesn't wrap. You have to use a different column type then.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, using the `threeparttable` package for the table notes, `siunitx` for the alignment of numbers, and _the `\addlinespace` command from `booktabs` instead of those series of (empty or not) multicolumns. Also, `caption` for a correct vertical spacing between caption and table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{array, makecell, booktabs, caption}
\setlength\defaultaddspace{1.5ex}
\usepackage[flushleft, para]{threeparttable}
\TPTnoteSettings{\footnotesize}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{table-format=1.2, table-number-alignment=center, table-space-text-pre=(, table-space-text-post=)\textsuperscript{**}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \centering
    \caption{Pruebas de placebo} \label{tab:placebo}%
    \begin{tabular}{lSS}
      \toprule
                                  & {(1)} & {(2)} \\
      Variables & {Número de operaciones -- ZINB} & {Desembolsos -- FEP} \\
      \midrule
      \addlinespace
      Placebo 6 meses & 0.05 & -0.11 \\
                                  & {(}0.06{)} & {(}0.16{)} \\
      \addlinespace
      Placebo 9 meses & -0.02 & -0.21 \\
                                  & {(}0.05{)} & {(}0.16{)} \\
      \addlinespace
      Placebo 12 meses & -0.09{\tnote{**}} & -0.31{\tnote{*}} \\
                                  & {(}0.04{)} & {(}0.16{)} \\
      \addlinespace
      Observaciones & {3,500} & {3,500} \\
      Efectos Fijos por Localidad & {SI} & {SI} \\
      Dummies Temporales & {SI} & {SI} \\
      Número de Localidades & {125} & {125} \\
      \bottomrule
      \addlinespace
    \end{tabular}%
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \item[]Nota: Período: septiembre 2011 a diciembre de 2013. Las variables placebo se definen como la variable tratamiento, rezagada 6, 9 y 12 meses. \\
      Solo se reporta esta variable; cada regresión incluye todos los controles utilizados en las Tablas \ref{tab:noperaciones}, \ref{tab:desembolsos} y \ref{tab:credprom}. Errores clúster a nivel de localidad,
      entre paréntesis.\\[1ex]
      \item[***] $ \mathrm p<0.01 $,
      \item [**] $ \mathrm p<0.05 $,
      \item[*] $ \mathrm p<0.1 $
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]  
\tiny
  \centering
  \caption{Pruebas de placebo}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\toprule
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)} \\
Variables & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Número de operaciones - ZINB} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Desembolsos - FEP} \\
    \midrule
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
Placebo 6 meses & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.05} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.11} \\
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.06)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.16)} \\
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
Placebo 9 meses & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.02} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.21} \\
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.05)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.16)} \\
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
Placebo 12 meses & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.09**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.31*} \\
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.04)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.16)} \\
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
Observaciones & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3,500} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3,500} \\
Efectos Fijos por Localidad & \multicolumn{1}{c}{SI} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{SI} \\
Dummies Temporales & \multicolumn{1}{c}{SI} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{SI} \\
Número de Localidades & \multicolumn{1}{c}{125} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{125} \\
\bottomrule
    \multicolumn{3}{p{0.9\linewidth}}{\textsuperscript{}\footnotesize{Nota: Período: septiembre 2011 a diciembre de 2013. Las variables placebo se definen como la variable tratamiento, rezagada 6, 9 y 12 meses.}} \\
    \multicolumn{3}{p{0.9\linewidth}}{\textsuperscript{}\footnotesize{Solo se reporta esta variable; cada regresión incluye todos los controles utilizados en las Tablas \ref{tab:noperaciones}, \ref{tab:desembolsos} y \ref{tab:credprom}. Errores clúster a nivel de localidad,}} \\
    \multicolumn{3}{p{0.9\linewidth}}{\textsuperscript{}\footnotesize{entre paréntesis. *** p<0.01, ** p<0.05, * p<0.1}}
\end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:placebo}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```